# HTTP Connection explanation required

Tags: java, android, http, httpconnection

I was using sockets to connect my android application to a server for sending messages. I am now trying to use an HTTP connection. The problem is, which one, and what must appear (HttpClient, HttpPost etc...), I have seen dozens of examples and I am struggling to understand them. I have heard the phrase handshake and all of the buzz words get, post... etc, but havent grasped at which point each is occouring.

I am simply asking for a basic insight into how an http connection is formed and then how we use the methods to send and recieve.

Thanks for any advice.

Simon

Comment: You certainly should know the HTTP protocol before you start using it.

Comment: Do you know of a good link for a detailed explanation of the HTTP protocol? Thanks

Comment: A good starting point is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/) shows a lot about getting (XML) data from the web. 

Here is a reference to the [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) that is used in that example.

There is also a **working downloadable eclipse project** on the website ( 1st link )

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

As an initial low level approach the wikipedia page seems quite good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol